# USB WiFi Stops Working

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

I use a USB wifi adapter on my desktop (TP-Link Archer T4U Plus). My wifi sometimes randomly disconnects, and I'm not sure why. Sometimes it's only for around 15 seconds, sometimes I need to connect to the other network (switch between 2.4ghz and 5ghz), sometimes I need to unplug the adapter and then plug it back in to get it to work.

Because of this, I bought a new, more expensive adapter (Netgear Nighthawk A7000) today and I'm having similar but different issues, ping spikes, high packet loss, occasional full disconnects.

I have tried plugging the adapters into different usb ports, restarting the computer multiple times, disabling disabling the usb to conserve power, and turned off auto configuration on my network devices. It is only my desktop that suffers from internet issues, so is the fault with my desktop? Or did I manage to get two bad devices?

Comment: Try updating the firmware on your router. That is possibly the issue.

Comment: You could start by measuring the signal strength with a Wifi analyzer, for example on your phone. The best WiFi NIC won't help if the router is garbage or if the signal is too weak or distorted. As with every wireless technology, every device transmitting on a similar frequency is a potential source of inteference, even a microwave or a electric motor.